# How to avoid using duplicate string literals in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to format the first input parameter 'str' to the function which is a date in string format coming from MySQL database and here i am trying to convert it to the format "%Y-%m-%d" at 4 different places which is kind of redundant at many places. Can someone please help me in telling how can i get rid of duplicating this literal everywhere? Here is my code -

```
def date_format(str, table, dc):
    try:
        print('it is running')
        date = ''
        str_len = len(str)
        rootLogger.info(f'the length of {str} is {str_len}')
        if str_len == 10:
            date = str
        if str_len == 19:
            date = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%Y-%m-%d")
        elif str_len == 20:
            date = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"), "%Y-%m-%d")
        elif str_len == 26:
            date = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"), "%Y-%m-%d")
        rootLogger.info(f'the date is {date}')

        return date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise

if __name__=="__main__":
    curr_dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    date_format('2011-01-13 06:12:41','test',8134)
```

Comment: don't use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: what name should i give it then if i know that it's a date value in string format coming from Mysql database?

Comment: You could use anything such as `dateStr` `Dstr` `date` `date_value_in_string_format_coming_from_Mysql_database` or anything else that is not a built-in.

Comment: ok thank you for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additiinal function

```
def get_date(date_str: str, format_: str):
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(date_str, format_), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

And use it as follows:

```
date = get_date(str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

*P.S. Avoid using built-in names as variable identificators*

Comment: even in your code you are using str in get_date function.Isn't it?

Comment: @Tushaar in usage example i did it, because he has his variable named that way

Comment: if you notice the format "%Y-%m-%d" code is present inside main function also, how to tackle it?

Comment: @sudden_appearance you should correct it in yours for future readers.

Comment: @Tushaar the format is taken care of with the `format_` variable `%Y-%m-%d"` is used the same way as it is in your code. No problem there.

Comment: @EliHarold i wrote a P.S. for that as you can see)

Comment: @sudden_appearance I noticed, but if people copy your code...

Comment: i am talking about this line curr_dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), how to handle the string literal here

Comment: @Tushaar, where are you using this value tho?

Comment: @Tushaar if you want you could put the formats in a list and call them from there.

Comment: @sudden_appearance I think he is wanting to avoid manually sending the function the "format".

Comment: i have to put these date field into bigquery table inside gcp

Comment: even now, i have to pass the date format three times in get_date function, can i create constants for them? but where will i store them?i want to access these different string literals inside many different functions, how will be it accessible everywhere

Comment: @Tushaar it's a question of architecture, which is to consider depends on your wishes. I showcased you how to shorten the writing, not how to lower the number of passes you will have.